# Why does the variable type change from list to tkinter PhotoImage?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a game in tkinter using the canvas as a small challenge.

I have a list with tkinter PhotoImages in it:

```
# Tiles as Tkinter PhotoImage Classes
tiles = []
for i in range(64):
    tiles.append(tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + f'\\graphics\\fr{i}.png'))
```

This is the only time I have used PhotoImages in my program.

I have a class for tiles:

```
# Game Object Class
class Object():

    def __init__(self, x, y, tag, ani_tiles):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tag = tag
        self.ani_tiles = ani_tiles # list of animation frames as tkinter PhotoImages
        self.ani_frame = 0
    
    # Draws sprite
    def draw_sprite(self):
        try:
            canvas.delete(self.id)
        except:
            pass
        self.id = canvas.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=tiles[self.ani_tiles[self.ani_frame]], tag=self.tag)
```

Which I am using later:

```
cRow = 0
    for row in self.screen:
        cCol = 0
        for tile in row:
            x = (cCol*TILE_RAD*2)+TILE_RAD
            y = (cRow*TILE_RAD*2)+TILE_RAD+(SCORE_HEIGHT*TILE_RAD*2)

            Object(x, y, tag='t', ani_tiles=[tile])
            cCol += 1
        cRow += 1
```

And I get this error:

```
self.id = canvas.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=tiles[self.ani_tiles[0]], tag=self.tag)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not PhotoImage
```

But if I do this:

```
Object(x, y, tag='t', ani_tiles=tile)
```

And this in the Object class:

```
self.id = canvas.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=tiles[self.ani_tiles], tag=self.tag)
```

Then I get this error:

```
self.id = canvas.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=tiles[self.ani_tiles], tag=self.tag)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Basically I don't understand why it says that it is a PhotoImage when it is (seemingly) a list, and why it says that it is a list when it is (also seemingly) an integer.

I'm just completely stumped with what to try, as I just can't figure out why the error is occuring.

Comment: `self.ani_tiles` is a list of `PhotoImage`s. `self.ani_tiles[0]` is a single `PhotoImage`, therefore `tiles[self.ani_tiles[0]]` is the try to access an item of list `tiles` with a `PhotoImage` as index (not allowed).

Comment: When you have nested lists, you can test each part to see what goes wrong. Before the bad line, add `print(idx:=self.ani_tiles[0])` and then `print(tiles[idx])`. You likely get something other than an integer on that first one and the second will fail. But it gives a good hint to the problem and a simpler example to post.

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code: `self.ani_tiles` is a `list` of `PhotoImage`s, and by doing `self.ani_tiles[0]`, you get a `PhotoImage`, but `self.ani_tiles[0]` is supposed to be an index itself, and `tiles` is a `list` of `PhotoImage`s as well, and `list[PhotoImage]` is not allowed because the index can only be an `int` or a slice.

The second block of code: As mentioned before, `self.ani_tiles` is a `list`, and `tiles` is a `list`. So you have a `list[list]`, which is impossible.

Hope this helps!